form-validation.js:3 jQuery Validation Plugin not loaded
I need some validation to work on the contact form but this not working. it shows the error on the browser "form-validation.js:3 jQuery Validation Plugin not loaded."
Here are the codes.
https://pastebin.pl/view/bb3037c1 - This is the javascript.
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Enjoy the finest coffee in Dublin at our cozy cafe."
/>
<!-- SEO - Provides a brief description of the page -->

<!-- SEO - Specifies keywords for the page. -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/contact.css" />
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load jQuery Validation Plugin -->
<script            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js">.   </script>

<script src="assets/js/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/form-validation.js" defer></script>

<title>Ashabi Bliss - Homepage</title>

<style></style>




  
    <h1>Ashabi Bliss</h1>
  

  <nav class="nosearch">
    <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Toggle navigation">☰</button>
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="./index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="./product.html">Products</a>
      <a href="./about.html">About</a>
      <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div class="searchcontainer" style="display: none">
      <form class="search-bar">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          aria-label="Search"
          class="search-input"
        />
        <button type="submit" class="search-button"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main class="main_content">
    <section class="form_section">
      <div class="form_section_content">
        <h1>SALES CONTACT FORM</h1>
        <form action="" id="contactForm">
          <label for="firstname"> Name(s)</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstname"
            name="firstname lastname"
            placeholder="Yours names.."
          />

          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Your email.."
          />

          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="phone"
            name="phone"
            placeholder="Your phone.."
          />

          <label for="productid">Product ID</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="productid"
            name="productid"
            placeholder="Enter Product id.."
          />

          <label for="message">Message</label>
          <textarea
            id="message"
            name="message"
            placeholder="Your Message.."
          ></textarea>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <small>&copy; 2024 Ashabi Bliss. All rights reserved.</small>
  </footer>
</div>

I tried to ensure that validations occurs in the contact form using the form-validation.js and for each field, it shows errors when necessary as defined in the js

It's very unclear what you're wanting to do or which plugin you're trying to use.  The  form-validation.js plugin is not the same as the jQuery Validate plugin.  Whichever one, the error means you're not including the plugin properly.

I am checking your library getting errors while using the browser.
Import the correct library from this link reference:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/

This are the library links:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js

